# Server behind nginx reverse proxy ignores relative path in URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

My title isn't the best, my knowledge of webstuff is quite basic, sorry.

## What I want to achieve

I have one box **fanbox** running nginx on Archlinux that I use as main entry point to my home LAN from the internet (namely work where I can only get out to port 80 and 443) via the reverse proxy facility using a changing domain name over which I have no control and that we will call **home.net** for now.

**fanbox** has its ports 80 and 443 mapped to **home.net**, that part was easy.

I have 2 webservers behind the firewall, **web1.lan**, **web2.lan**, **web2ilo.lan**. Both of these have various applications (which may have same name on different machines) that can directly be accessed on the LAN via standard URLs (the names are given as examples, I have no control over the content):

```
http://web1.lan/phpAdmin/
http://web1.lan/gallery/
http://web2.lan/phpAdmin/
http://web2.lan/dlna/
```

...and so on...

Now **web2ilo.lan** is a particular case. It's the out of band management web interface of the HP server **web2.lan**. That particular webserver offers only 1 application, so it can only be accessed via its root URL:

```
http://web2ilo/login.html
```

My goal is to access these via subpath of **home.net** like this:

```
http://home.net/web1/phpAdmin/
http://home.net/web1/gallery/
http://home.net/web2/phpAdmin/
http://home.net/web2/dlna/
http://home.net/web2ilo/login.html
```

## My problem

That nearly works but the web applications tend to rewrite URLs so that after I login to, respectively:

```
http://home.net/web1/phpAdmin/login.php
http://home.net/web2ilo/login.html
```

the browser is redirected respectively to

```
http://home.net/phpAdmin/index.php
http://home.net/index.html
```

Note that the relative subpaths **web1** and **web2ilo** have gone, which logically give me a 404.

## My config

So far, I've searched a lot and I tried many options in nginx without understanding too much what I was doing. Here is my config that reproduces this problem. I've left SSL out for clarity.

```
   server {
      listen       443 ssl;
      server_name  localhost;

      # SSL stuff left out for clarity 

      location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index  index.html index.htm;
      }

      location /web1/ {
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_pass https://web1.lan/;
      }


      location /web2/ {
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_pass https://web2.lan/;
      }

      location /web2ilo/ {
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_pass https://web2ilo.lan/;
      }

  }
```

## After first answers

After the first couple of answers (thanks!), I realise that my setup is far from common and that I may be heading for trouble all alone.

What would then be a better idea to access the webserver behind the firewall without touching frontend ports and domain/hostname ?

Comment: You explicitly disable url rewriting with `proxy_redirect off` and expect it to work. Funny.

Comment: I followed examples that I found googling... I've tried several parameters for this option but can hardly notice any difference. So I guess my whole approach is totally wrong. Not funny no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an answer to my question and decided to try a different approach:

- I now have containerized most of my servers
- I use Traefik (https://containo.us/traefik/) as my "fanbox" (= reverse proxy) as it covers my needs but also solves in a quite easy fashion the SSL certificates stuff.

Thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: How did you achieve this in traefik 2.0? With `stripprefix` I couldn't get this. Traefik didn't respect the relative path.

Comment: @IvanGonzalez Answers in comment are limited to 512 characters so I'm adding a new answer. See below.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider the use of setting `proxy_redirect` to let nginx know that it should modify the "backend" server response headers (Location and Refresh) to the appropriate front-end URLs. You can either use the `default` setting to allow nginx to calculate the appropriate values from your `location` and `proxy_pass` directives, or explicitly specify the mappings like below:

```
proxy_redirect http://web1.lan/ /web1/
```

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

*Note:* This only affects response headers - not any links in HTML content, or any Javascript.

If you experience problems with links in content or Javascript, you can either modify the content on the backend servers (which you've indicated may not be possible), or adjust your proxy solution such that front end paths are the same as the back end ones (e.g., rather than `http://frontend/web1/phpAdmin` you simply have `http://frontend/phpAdmin`). This would entail adding `location` directives for each application, e.g.,

```
location /phpAdmin/ {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass https://web1.lan/phpAdmin/;
}
```

Comment: Point 1: I have tried both but not enough to notice any difference. I will read the doc and run tests.

Comment: Point 2: Sounds good but it fails to cover one particular case that I did not mention in my question... I did not think that it would be needed. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested example.

In my docker-compose.yml I use the demo image **whoami** to test:

```
whoareyou:
  image: "containous/whoami"
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
   - default
  labels:
   - "traefik.enable=true"

   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou.rule=Path(`/whoareyou`)"
   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou.entrypoints=web"
   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou.middlewares=https-redirect@file"

   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou-secure.rule=Path(`/whoareyou`)"
   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou-secure.entrypoints=web-secure"
   - "traefik.http.routers.whoareyou-secure.tls=true"
```

In my config.yaml I have my https redirect:

```
http:
  middlewares:
    https-redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
```